# Prevent elements within a div from scrolling with rest of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I think the problem is, that the div in which the content is nested has no id or class but only the attribute `<div role="main"> ... </div>`
Within it i have elements that are `<div id="description">`, `<p>` and `<h2>`. Those i wish to prevent from being scrolled (the text needs to remain readable in its entirety) while a table within the div is being scrolled.

I attempted to solve the problem with a short JQuery-script that was supposed to compensate for the scroll, but i am neither sure if that approach Would work, nor How to select the div by its "role" attribute for it.

Here is what i have up to now:

```
var leftOffset = parseInt($("#description").css('left'));
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var newOffset = num.toString($(this).scrollLeft() * -1 + leftOffset),
    $('#description').css("left", newOffset);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't fully understand your question. I think you have a div (with role="main") with some content. You want the content to scroll normally except one or two elements (div with id="description", p and h2). You can add a div inside div[role=main]. Put the content which you want to scroll in it and the content which should not scroll inside div[role=main]. This way you are creating a div with same size inside div[role=main] and letting its content scroll and prevent scrolling on div[role=main]. Preventing scrolling of specific content is not possible but keeping the content that should and should not scroll in different divs should work.

```
div[role="main"] {
    position: relative;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
div[role="main"] .scroll {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

<div role="main">
    ...content which should not scroll
    <div class="scroll">
        ...content which should scroll
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the div by `$('[role=main]')`
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_equal_value.asp

You can disable scrolling of an element using CSS

```
[role=main] {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Would that work for this in order to make everything BUT this div scroll within the [role="main"] div?
    [id="description"] {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

Answer (score 0):

you may use the selector `[role="main"]` via CSS or jQuery,  and maybe`position:sticky` in CSS *(if i understood cause without more code of yours i do not get the point :) )*

see http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/ for the sticky position

```css
[role="main"] {/* demo purpose*/
  display:inline-flex;
  height:400px;;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#description , [role="main"] h2{
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  width:280px;
  position:sticky;
  left :0;
  top:0;
  background:yellow;
}
p {/* force horizontal scrolling for demo*/
  width:100%;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div role="main">
  <div id="description">
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
        
<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. </p>
  </div>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.<strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.<strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
```

Comment: If i run the code snipped, everything here is scrolled.
What i would like to achieve however is f.e. if the <h1> were on top, that everything BUT that scrolls.

Comment: @lolcat Can you set a http://codepen.io/pen with your html , and add color : red to what you do not want to scroll. I'm confused reading your comments and question , once i understand you want #description and h2 to stay still, but then not H1 or only #description. Your HTML structure will help you  In order to be able to answer you correctly and propose you something relevant if this is the case